# SUM until a certain point

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table of inventory transactions. I need to select the dates of the last few transactions, up until the adjusted quantity is greater then the current amount on hand in inventory.

I am dealing with three columns: `item, transaction_date, adj_qty`. Each item will have multiple transaction dates and adjustment quantities.

How do I return the all the transaction_dates for each item until the item reached a certain threshold (i.e. accumulate 100). Say the first item has 2000 transactions and the last five transactions have each a qty of 21. I would like the query to return transaction the last 5 because that is when the item reached 100.

If possible I'd like to do this without a loop or cursor.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a cumulative sum.  This is built into SQL Server 2012.

Alas, with that, you need to do it with a self join:

```
select t.item, t.transaction_date, t.adj_qty, 
       sum(tprev.adj_qty) as CumSum
from t t join
     t tprev
     on t.item = tprev.item and
        t.transaction_date >= tprev.transaction_date
group by t.item, t.transaction_date, t.adj_qty
having 100 between sum(tprev.adj_qty) -t.adj_qty + 1 and sum(tprev.adj_qty)
```

Notice the use of the self join and group by to do the cumulative sum.  Not pleasant, but necessary without the order clause in the SUM() over (partition by) function.  This cumulative sum adds everything up from the first record (by transaction date) for an item up to any other.

The HAVING clause then selects the row you are looking for, where the cumulative sum has increased passed some threshhold.

Comment: Wow! This solution is brilliant! Just what I needed. Thanks so much!

Comment: I just used this idea for another challenge I had. this time doing it backwards! subtracting each line from the one before. Thanks again for your help.